# How do I get a property value from an object in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, date, foreach

I iterate through an array(using a foreach loop) that contains two 'High Season' objects - the two objects have an id, start date and end date. I get the high season start date via getter and assign it to a variable with intentions of incrementing the month when I loop through the date difference of the high season's start date and end date. When I loop through the date difference, the Booking start date and end date are compared against the variable I have been incrementing by month, and then the variable "containing" the date is incremented by one month.

Does this variable contain a reference to the array's high season object's start date property? when I dump the high seasons array the start date has changed to the same date as the variable that has been incremented by one month. How do I get the value of the high season start date property and not the reference of the array object's start date?

I am using PHP 5.5.30.

```
foreach ($highseasons as $highseason) {
    $HSDate = $highseason->getStartDate();
    $diff = date_diff($highseason->getStartDate(), $highseason->getEndDate());

    $months = (int)$diff->format('%m');
    $SDBool = false;
    $EDBool = false;

    // loop through the date difference
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $months; $i++) {
        var_dump($highseasons);
        $HSMonth = $HSDate->format('m');
        $BookingStartingMonth = $value->getStartDate()->format('m');
        $BookingEndingMonth = $value->getEndDate()->format('m');

        if ($HSMonth == $BookingStartingMonth) {
            $SDBool = true;
        }

        if ($HSMonth == $BookingEndingMonth) {
            $EDBool = true;
        }

        // add one month onto the high season date
        $HSDate->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the start date is a DateTime object, yes it is a reference and modifying it will change the value of the highseason's start date as well (since they are the same object).

In order to do what you are asking for, you need to `clone` the DateTime object:

```
$tempDate = clone $HSDate;
```

and increment the new date object instead.